# How to retrieve a specific solution when there are multiple solutions for an integral using sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

Frequently, when I'm solving integrals the result happen to be a multiple solution with one equation for each interval. For example, the computation of the density function of a random variable (say Z) give by the ratio of two standard normal variables (say X and Y) is the integral of the following expression:

[image]

The computation of integral gives:

```py
expr=Rational(1/2)*(1/pi)*abs(y)*exp(-pow(y,2)*(pow(z,2)+1)/2)
result=integrate(expr,(y,-oo,+oo))
result
```

[image]

I would like to retrieve the first expression as a new variable. I tried `equation=result[0]` which didn't work. I also inspect the methods associate to `result` using `dir`. I tried a few of them like `getO`, and `extract_branch_factor()`, without success.

Is there a way to get only the first expression in the solution as a new variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you get this case because you have not specified any properties ("assumptions") on the symbol `z`, If you do then you can get the result more simply:

```
In [43]: z = Symbol('z', real=True)

In [44]: expr=Rational(1/2)*(1/pi)*abs(y)*exp(-pow(y,2)*(pow(z,2)+1)/2)

In [45]: expr
Out[45]: 
   2 ⎛ 2    ⎞     
 -y ⋅⎝z  + 1⎠     
 ─────────────    
       2          
ℯ             ⋅│y│
──────────────────
       2⋅π        

In [46]: integrate(expr,(y,-oo,+oo))
Out[46]: 
    1     
──────────
  ⎛ 2    ⎞
π⋅⎝z  + 1⎠
```

You have presumably created `z` as a plain symbol without the `real=True` condition so you get:

```
In [47]: z = Symbol('z')

In [48]: expr=Rational(1/2)*(1/pi)*abs(y)*exp(-pow(y,2)*(pow(z,2)+1)/2)

In [49]: integrate(expr,(y,-oo,+oo))
Out[49]: 
⎧           1                  │   ⎛ 2    ⎞│   π
⎪       ──────────         for │arg⎝z  + 1⎠│ < ─
⎪         ⎛ 2    ⎞                             2
⎪       π⋅⎝z  + 1⎠                              
⎪                                               
⎪∞                                              
⎪⌠                                              
⎪⎮     2 ⎛ 2    ⎞                               
⎨⎮   -y ⋅⎝z  + 1⎠                               
⎪⎮   ─────────────                              
⎪⎮         2                                    
⎪⎮  ℯ             ⋅│y│                          
⎪⎮  ────────────────── dy        otherwise      
⎪⎮         2⋅π                                  
⎪⌡                                              
⎪-∞                                             
⎩
```

If you want the first expression from there you can do it by accessing `.args`:

```
In [51]: integrate(expr,(y,-oo,+oo)).args[0][0]
Out[51]: 
    1     
──────────
  ⎛ 2    ⎞
π⋅⎝z  + 1⎠
```